# Unhandle exception issue

Tags: vb.net, exception, unhandled

We have a large app built using VB.NET VS2012. Every now and then when closing the app an `unhandled exception` occurs. Very random, sometimes it does it sometimes it doesn't.

The error is below.

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Post(SendOrPostCallback d, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.ConnectionPointCookie.Finalize()
  InnerException:
```

We produce a dump file to try and find where this is originating but have had no luck. The debugger just shows `No source code available`. We *are* using some third-party controls. At this point we just want to find what is trying to create the control. If its a problem with the third party control and if we don't have that code, we can't fix it but maybe we can work around it. But we can't find what is trying to create control (when shutting down).

We have reviewed many web posts describing how to utilize the crash dump files but have had no luck identifying the control (or even the control type) that is generating this.. Just knowing the type would help narrow it down.

Any ideas how we can at least get the type of control or the originating caller or?

If enough info isn't provided please let me know and I will post what I can.

Posting code is not an option because we have no idea where the message is coming from.

Thanks in advance!

I should have added that we do use try catch blocks for just about everything. We also do have a logging procedure but we arent seeing any of these exceptions in the log file.

Comment: since it happens when ending, you could log each step in the process (whatever it is Form_closing or a custom App Exit method).  Wherever the log stops is where to start looking

Comment: We have nothing in the closing event and no custom app exit.

Comment: I should have added that we do use try catch blocks for just about everything. We also do have a logging procedure but we arent seeing any of these exceptions in the log file.

Comment: You should be able to focus on the `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke` methods and poss a custom control per the exception.

Comment: OneFineDay: Can you elaborate on your comment please?

Comment: Well, this is bad. When a control gets to this code then odds are indeed not good that it won't bomb, especially so when exiting. It is not getting cleaned-up the normal way, getting disposed when the host form closes. In other words, you have a "leak". Could be that you are removing it with Controls.Remove/At() or Clear() and forgetting to dispose it. Could be another bug in your program causing it to bomb, then triggering this one. You need a code review, a memory profiler and a talk with the user.